# How to access pointer member variable using this pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, this, dereference

class paper{

```
private:
int length;
int *width;

public:
void set_data(int length, int width){
    cout<<"inside set data"<<endl;
    this->length=length;
    this->width=&width;
}
void show_data(){
    cout<<"inside show_data"<<endl;
    cout<<this->length;cout<<this->(*width);
    cout<<this->(*width);
}
```

};

getting error for
cout<(*width);

How to dereference pointer using this pointer

Comment: Do you mean `*( this->width )` ?

Comment: Why is `width` an `int*` at all instead of an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by replacing `this->(*width)` with:

```
*(this->width)
```

The program then works as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/9s6u_5nXH).

Comment: This program _compiles_, but if you actually used `set_data` and `show_data` you'd get undefined behavior. `this->width = &width` sets `this->width` to be a pointer to a temporary variable, so dereferencing it after that variable's lifetime has ended is UB.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes the OP should take care of that accordingly/appropriately.